# Why does mic.getLevel() not go to 0 again after getAudioContext().suspend() is called?

Tags: dom, audio, p5.js

Making a voice recorder visualizer and I'm just about finished but there's one thing, After I stop the recording, the values in mic.getLevel() do not go back to 0 but instead it seems like the last value that was recorded in mic.getLeve() is stored permanently and added to the height of my ellipse so the ellipse would then have a height of some value rather than 0 which it started with, is there anyway to fix this?

```js
var recordAudio;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  recordAudio = new AudioFile()
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  recordAudio.draw();
  recordAudio.setup();
  recordAudio.drawBorder();
  recordAudio.drawNode();

}

function AudioFile() {
  this.nodes = [];
  var speed = 2;
  var endBorder;
  var mic = new p5.AudioIn();
  var micLevel;
  var level;
  var recorder = new p5.SoundRecorder();
  var soundFile = new p5.SoundFile();
  var button = createButton('Start Recording');
  var state = 0;

  this.draw = function() {
    background(0);

    level = mic.getLevel();
    micLevel = floor(map(level, 0, 0.6545, 0, 50));

  }
  this.drawNode = function() {
    if (frameCount % 5 == 0) {
      this.addNode()
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
      var node = this.nodes[i]

      for (var j = 0; j < node.length; j++) {
        fill(255);
        node[j].x -= speed;
        ellipse(node[j].x, node[j].y, node[j].width, node[j].height)
      }
      if (node[0].x < endBorder) {
        this.nodes.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }

  this.drawBorder = function() {
    var x = windowWidth / 9;
    var y = windowHeight / 10;
    var width = (windowWidth / 9) * 7;
    var height = windowHeight - y * 2;

    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    noFill();
    rect(x, y, width, height);
  }
  this.addNode = function() {
    this.nodes.push(
      [{
        x: ((windowWidth / 9) * 8) - 10,
        y: windowHeight / 2,
        width: 5,
        height: 5 * micLevel
      }])
  }

  this.setup = function() {
    endBorder = windowWidth / 9 + 5;

    mic.start();
    recorder.setInput(mic);

    button.position(windowWidth / 9, windowHeight / 10);
    button.style('font-size', '18px');
    button.mousePressed(this.recording)
  }
  this.recording = function() {
    if (state === 0 && mic.enabled) {
      button.html("Stop Recording");
      getAudioContext().resume()
      recorder.record(soundFile);
      state++
    } else if (state === 1) {
      button.html("Start Recording");
      getAudioContext().suspend();
      recorder.stop();
      state++;
    } else if (state === 2) {
      save(soundFile, 'Sound.wav');
      state = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="p5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="p5.dom.js"></script>
  <script src="p5.sound.js"></script>

  <script src="sketch.js"></script>

  <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">-->
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Button">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a global variable called listening and used that in an if statement in draw to set the  level to either mic.getLevel() or 0 based on if listening is true or false.